# C# spawn new task

Tags: c#

Suppose I have this function:

```
void DoWork()
{
   //do long work
}
```

I want this function to be executed on a different thread.
I'm used to use threads, so one way to execute it on a thread is:

```
new Thread(DoWork).Start();
```

I'm trying to learn the new `task/await` C# feature so I modified the method to

```
async Task DoWork()
{
    await Task.Run(delegate() { /*do stuff*/});
}
```

Now I can use it this way:

```
DoWork().Wait(0);
```

Or I can modify the method again to:

```
async void DoWork()
{
    await Task.Run(delegate() { /*do stuff*/});
}
```

And now just call:

```
DoWork();
```

Which solution should I use ?
I do not need the result of the task nor waiting for it to finish.

Comment: I found this video quite useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_GTdR0gBVE

Comment: as a reference for knowledge http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html

Comment: If you don't need result of the task nor waiting for it to finish - what's the reason to use `async/await`? You can run task and forget about it: `Task.Run(() => { /*do stuff*/})`. `async/await` is useful when you need to do some job after task finshed.

Comment: @ Kirill Shlenskiy Correct my bad, Task.Wait, WhenAll are blocking not Task.Run or Start per se, please ignore my last comment as a mistake

Comment: `I do not need the result of the task nor waiting for it to finish.` But do you also want to silently ignore any exceptions?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is neither. You are creating a trivial asynchronous wrapper around synchronous logic.

Stephen Cleary: [using Task.Run for asynchronous wrappers is a code smell](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Stephen Toub (Microsoft): [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) (and no, you shouldn't).

The async part of your `DoWork` method adds no value. It *diminishes* the value of your API by making it impossible to execute your potentially complex *"do stuff"* logic in any way other than fire-and-forget.

The correct approach is to ditch `Task.Run` and strip your method down to the bare essentials:

```
void DoWork()
{
   // Do long CPU-bound work, synchronously
}

...

// Then, somewhere in the calling code:
Task.Run(() => DoWork()); // Fire and forget unless you await the resulting Task or block on it.
```

`Task.Run` is currently the preferred method of scheduling work on the thread pool (as of .NET 4.6.x)

Comment: +1. Also, if you *really* want fire-and-forget (which is *not* actually the case >90% of the time people *ask* for fire-and-forget), you can avoid the warning by doing `var _ = Task.Run(() => DoWork());`